# preventing the button from moving its position when resizing the size of screen

Tags: html, css

I tried different ways to fix the position of my button when changing the size of the screen, I tried `position: relative` but still moved. I look up here with the same problem but all the answers are not working with my code. I can't think what I can do about this problem it seems like I tried all the `display:` but still doesn't work.

CSS

```
:root {
  --color1: hsl(31, 77%, 52%);
  --color2: hsl(184, 100%, 22%);
  --color3: hsl(179, 100%, 13%);

  --paragraphWhite: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.75);
  --headingsWhite: hsl(0, 0%, 95%);

  --fontParagraph: "Lexend Deca", sans-serif;
  --fontDisplay: "Big Shoulders Display", sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: var(--fontParagraph);
  background-color: var(--headingsWhite);
  color: var(--paragraphWhite);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  /* max-width: 500px; */
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 450px;
  max-width: 1020px;
}

.sedan,
.suv,
.luxury {
  padding: 12% 15% 12% 15%;
}

.icon {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.title {
  font-family: var(--fontDisplay);
  color: var(--headingsWhite);
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.text {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.btnBox {
  padding-top: 6rem;
 
}

.button {
  border: none;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 1em;
}

.sedan .button {
  color: var(--color1);
}

.suv .button {
  color: var(--color2);
}

.luxury .button {
  color: var(--color3);
}
.sedan {
  background-color: var(--color1);
}

.suv {
  background-color: var(--color2);
}

.luxury {
  background-color: var(--color3);
}

.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}
.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <main>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sedan">
          <img src="/images/icon-sedans.svg" alt="sedan" class="icon" />
          <h1 class="title">Sedans</h1>
          <p class="text">
            Choose a sedan for its affordability and excellent fuel economy.
            Ideal for cruising in the city or on your next road trip.
          </p>
          <div class="btnBox">
            <button class="button">Learn More</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="suv">
          <img src="/images/icon-suvs.svg" alt="" class="icon" />
          <h1 class="title">SUVs</h1>
          <p class="text">
            Take an SUV for its spacious interior, power, and versatility.
            Perfect for your next family vacation and off-road adventures.
          </p>

          <div class="btnBox"><button class="button">Learn More</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="luxury">
          <img src="/images/icon-luxury.svg" alt="" class="icon">
          <h1 class="title">Luxury</h1>
          <p class="text">
            Cruise in the best car brands without the bloated prices. Enjoy the
            enhanced comfort of a luxury rental and arrive in style.
          </p>

          <div class="btnBox"><button class="button">Learn More</button></div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
      <div class="attribution">
        Challenge by
        <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank"
          >Frontend Mentor</a
        >. Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
```

Comment: `position: fixed`?

Comment: margin: 0 auto;?
position: fixed;?

Comment: I put it in the .btnBox and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 450px;
}
.wrapper > div {
  --size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--size) + 35px);
}
.btnBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  bottom: var(--size);
}
```

Comment: I did this and all content inside the box got bigger lol also the button still moving when scaling down the screen size

Comment: Can take a screenshot to explain your problem?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/892VT3w the icon got big and it push down the content below.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.